# Is there anyway to make a drawable transparent in XML?

Tags: android, xml

I'm wanting to overwrite the color property of a drawable (specifically the switch thumb) and make it transparent, I realise this can be done programatically, but is there a way to do it in the XML itself?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012" />
<item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001" />
</selector>
```

The above code seems to have had no effect on the color

Answer (score 0):

what about using an empty one ? define yourself an empty drawable with matching height and width.

And keep in mind Android does not work that way (sadly), overwriting is not possible in drawables, but it would be a nice to have, but althought would lead to misuse as this consumes raw power wich might be not available on some devices.